# Why is BigDecimal.divide() giving me a wrong answer?

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I am currently using BigDecimal types for a project, and they've been working great.

Except for very large values - each divide appears to be giving me an unusually round and incorrect answer.

Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
System.out.print("a: "+a+", b: "+b);
i = a.divide(b, mc).setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
System.out.println(", result: "+i);
```

And I am getting printouts such as:

```
a: 100000000000106, b: 1.414213562373095048801688724209699005327534773448623528143294164, result: 70000000000000
a: 100000000000022, b: 1.414213562373095048801688724209699005327534773448623528143294164, result: 70000000000000
a: 100000000000036, b: 1.414213562373095048801688724209699005327534773448623528143294164, result: 70000000000000
```

When I plug these three divides into a calculator, they each give me roughly 70710678118704. However the BigDecimal divide is giving me an even 70000000000000.

Does this have to do with me rounding incorrectly?

Note: All types (a, b, and i) are all BigDecimals

Edit: Added the instantiation of mc:

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(1, RoundingMode.DOWN);
```

Comment: Please show the line where you initialise `mc`.

Comment: There you go. Sorry I missed it. Is that what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your division, you are providing a `MathContext` argument, which controls how many significant figures your division will use.  Your results indicate that you are EITHER

- using a `MathContext` with a precision of 1; OR
- using a `MathContext` with a precision of 2, but a rounding mode that rounds down.

That is, you're only ever going to divide to one or two significant figures.

You need to create a different `MathContext` object, with a higher value for precision, for example,

```
mc = new MathContext(10);
```

if you want division to 10 significant figures.

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Thank you. I'll accept as soon as stackoverflow lets me.